# jquery parsing error Json object from asp.net weservice

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

This is a JSON object which is being returned from asp.net webservice.

```
[{"fullname":"martin","isAdmin":false,"Latitude":47,"Longitude":-124,"isOnline":false},
{"fullname":"melvyn","isAdmin":false,"Latitude":47,"Longitude":-124,"isOnline":true},
{"fullname":"simon","isAdmin":false,"Latitude":47,"Longitude":-124,"isOnline":false}]
```

when I use an alert in jquery

```
  $(function () {
            $("#btnShow").click(function () {
               $.ajax(
               {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "WS_PfaMembers.asmx/GetPFAMembersForMap",
                 data: "{}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (msg) {
                     alert(msg);
                 },
                 failure: function (msg) {
                     alert('error');
                 }

               });
           });
       });
```

The alert of `msg` is giving `object Object`.

How do I parse the object?

Comment: Try `console.log(msg)` and look in the JavaScript console. This will show the detailed structure of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by parse. If you want to iterate over the json object.. ??

If so try this

```
success : function(msg){

     $.each(msg , function(){
        $.each(this , function(i,value){
           console.log('The value of : ' + i + ' is - ' + value);  
        });
      });
}
```

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/LacBx/)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to print out a returned JSON object and expect to get the contents of it directly using just alert on the object. What you can do is to parse the code using the jQuery.parseJSON method. Take a look at:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 0):

[W3SCHOOLS.COM](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

If im correct!

```
alert(msg[0].fullname);
```

will give you
martin